# NSRangeException in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview, nsrangeexception

This is my code within `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method,

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
NSDictionary *temp = [self.placeArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.textLabel.text = [temp objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[temp objectForKey:@"distance"] stringByAppendingString:@" km from Banglore"];
cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[temp objectForKey:@"category"]];
return cell;
```

I get exception,

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Tableview Delegate is like,

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.placeArray.count;
}
```

Otherwise let me know...

Comment: Just `NSLog` your array count and indexPath.row.. if it is ok, the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Array Count is returning zero in NSlog , Where is the bug ?

Comment: Put the `NSLog` in `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate method. check here array count and let me know.

Comment: @Yammer what happened??

Comment: Sorry for late reply , i did NSLog in numbetofRowsinSection .. It is returning 28.

Comment: Do'nt know how , but the code is working now , just i can't see image in tableview , can you help me with this issue ?

Comment: have you given your image key "category" in temp dictionary corrrectly? can you show your dictionary structure?

Answer (score 1):

Exception itself provide you the answer. 
Your `self.placeArray` contains only 3 elements and you are trying to create more than 3 cells. You need to make sure that the `self.placeArray`'s count was returning in `numberOfRowsInSection` method and also this array is not updating asynchronously while tableview is reloading.

Answer (score 1):

The value you return in numberOfRowsForSection is greater than the number of objects in the placeArray.

after the line

```
NSDictionary *temp = [self.placeArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

add this

```
NSLog(@"number of places = %i", [placeArray count]);
```

Add a breakpoint at that line. You'll see that the app will crash when it hits this break point the fourth time, because numberOfRowsInSection is returning > 3 rows, and your placeArray has only <=3 objects